# Bourne Shell Conditional Operators

Tags: conditional-statements, sh

I am having a lot of fun playing with Bourne Shell, but I am facing a quite cryptic situation regarding conditions:

```
#! /bin/sh

a=1
b=2
c="0 kB/s"

if [ "$a" -eq 1 ] ; then echo "a = 1: true" ; else echo "a =  1: false" ; fi
if [ "$b" -gt 0 ] ; then echo "b > 0: true" ; else echo "b > 0: false" ; fi
if [ "$c" != "0 kB/s" ] ; then echo "c <> 0: true" ; else echo "c <> 0: false" ; fi
if [ "$a" -eq 1 ] || [ "$b" -gt 0 ] ; then echo "a = 1 or b > 0: true" ; else echo "a = 1 or b > 0: false" ; fi
if [ "$a" -eq 1 ] || [ "$b" -gt 0 ] && [ "$c" != "0 kB/s" ] ; then echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: true" ; else echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: false" ; fi
if [ true ] || [ true ] && [ false ] ; then echo "true or true and false: true" ; else echo "true or true and false: false" ; fi
```

gives me the following result:

```
a = 1: true
b > 0: true
c <> 0: false
a = 1 or b > 0: true
a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: false
true or true and false: true
```

Short question: why don't I get `a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: true`?

Thanks a lot for your help ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` and `&&` have equal precedence, unlike in languages where the logical AND operator binds more tightly than the logical OR. This means your code as written is equivalent to

```
if { [ "$a" -eq 1 ] || [ "$b" -gt 0 ]; } && [ "$c" != "0 kB/s" ] ; then
  echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: true"
else
  echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: false"
fi
```

rather than the expected

```
if [ "$a" -eq 1 ] || { [ "$b" -gt 0 ] && [ "$c" != "0 kB/s" ]; } ; then
  echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: true"
else
  echo "a = 1 or b > 0 and c <> 0: false"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but then why do I anyway get `true or true and false: true`?

Comment: Because `true` and `false` are not Boolean constants; they are just non-empty strings, so `[ true ]` and `[ false ]` both succeed (they are equivalent to `[ -n true ]` and `[ -n false ]`, respectively).